# What can I get with debugger information that I cant get with reflection?

Tags: java, debugging, reflection

I was told recently that if you look at the debug information of a Java program you can get a lot more information about it than you could with reflection. I realized though that I dont really know what, perhaps with the exception of memory locations and such. So what else can you get with debugging information that you can't get with reflection (Note: I am not talking about using breakpoints to get actual runtime values)? And is there any information that you can get with reflection that you cant get from the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

im going to assume that by "with debugger information" you actually mean "using the [agent API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140680.html)", which is what debuggers (among others) use.

the answer is quite a lot.

for startes the JVMTI can [force garbage collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#ForceGarbageCollection), which no pure java API can.
this can, for specific types of applications and contrary to common wisdom, be useful at times even for "production" code.

you could also instrument classes as they load. this is useful for various profiler tools, obfuscation of your compiled code (encrypted class files) and even changing loaded classes on the fly in response to changes in source code (see [jrebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/) for a good example)

Comment: Not to mention your agent is running in C rather than Java, so you can change literally anything you want about the process since there are no memory safety constraints. One other thing that's available through the API though is access to variables in other higher-level stack frames and metadata about the stack frames themselves. You can use the APIs via the `jdwp` agent if you prefer to write code in a separate Java process as well (I believe this is what most debugging tools do).